# Send DataTable as POST data

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm using laravel and dataTables. This is my view with dataTables work fine and limit the table 12 rows per paging.

```
@foreach($products as $result)
    <tr class="even pointer">
    <input name="id{{ $idx }}" value="{{ $result->id }}" type="hidden">
        <td class="a-center "><input value="{{ $result->qtyorder }}" name="qty{{ $idx }}" type="text"></td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $result->item }}</td>
        <td class=" "><input value="{{ $result->discount }}" name="price{{ $idx }}" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $idx++; ?>
@endforeach
```

the problem is when i click submit it's just send 12 data, and not sent the data on page 2, 3, ...
when i try next to page 2 and submint, only data at page 2 sent..

How to sent all data?

Answer (score 0):

For the best practice, wrap your table in a form and put the data you want to post but not display to the user in hidden inputs

```
<form method="post" action="">
<!-- your table -->
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="VALUE/>
<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="VALUE1/>
<input type="hidden" name="name2" value="VALUE2/>
<button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Alternative way, easy but not a good practice is using JQuery / Javascript
to run over the table and get html(text) attribute. Ex.

```
var columns = [
        'cl001',
        'cl002',
        'cl003'
    ];

 var tableObj = $('#tableID tbody tr').map(function (i) {
        var row = {};
        $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
            var rowID = columns[i];
            row[rowID] = $(this).text();
        });
        return row;
    }).get();


$.post( "ACTIONURL", { data: tableObj })
.done(function( data ) {
console.log( data );
});
```

Comment: how if the row count is depend on product data on database?

Comment: if you really want to display data from database in to html and then submit back in to your backend program you just query all row you want into the table and try above solution.